# Jtable Data selected row do not populate in jDialog form

Tags: java, sql, swing, swingx, swing-app-framework

I am new in Java programming.

My problem is, I have two forms in my project. "Product" form and "Edit Product" form(Prod_Edit), like this picture:

[image]

I want that by pressing Edit button jtable selected row data should populate in the text fields of edit form (jdialog form).

[image]

But as picture shows that text fields are blanks.

I have this code, in action perform of edit button.

```
Prod_Edit  PE = new Prod_Edit (this,true);    
PE.setVisible(true);    
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tblShowAllData.getModel();    
int selectedRowIndex = tblShowAllData.getSelectedRow();       
PE.txtId.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());     
PE.txtName.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());     
PE.txtAbri.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 2).toString());               

this.dispose();
```

What change should I do in this code or should I put some code in edit jdialog form open windows event?